# Issue in accessing package variable in Dreamweaver Template

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, dwt

I am facing a issue in accessing a package variable in DWT of Page Template.

I have a compound page template with 4 TBB's as follows:

1) **Constant TBB** - This TBB reads all values of a component(Embedded multivalued component) as key-value pairs and pushes them to a package.
    E.g :

```
Item item = this._package.CreateStringItem(contentType, "test");
this._package.PushItem("key", item);
```

2) **C# DLL of Page Template** - This contains the logic of Page Template

3) **DWT of Page Template** - All package variables are outputted here.

4) **Default Finish Actions**

The issue I am facing is as follows:

In my DWT ,I want to compare the Metadata of Component template with the package variable set in Constant TBB.

The syntax I am using is :

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="ComponentTemplate.Metadata.section_name = key" -->
```

where key is the package name set in constant TBB having value "test"

But somehow this package variable "key" is giving a value of 0 and not test.

Can someone let me know where exactly I am going wrong.

Comment: Try: <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="ComponentTemplate.Metadata.section_name `==` key" -->

Comment: How did you check the variable value to as 0? Try @@key@@ before condition and see what you get and then compare with a package variable in template builder.

Comment: I had tried this as well:<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="ComponentTemplate.Metadata.section_name == key" --> It does not seem to work.

Comment: Hi Vikas,
I checked it the same way using @@key@@ and then I found out it is giving value as 0 . But in template builder in the package it shows me correct value as "test".

Answer (score 6):

You should specify the type of item that you're adding to the package by replacing:

```
Item item = this._package.CreateStringItem(contentType, "test");
```

with

```
Item item = this._package.CreateStringItem(contentType.Text, "test");
```

You should also confirm that the variable is being passed properly to DWT by using

```
@@test@@
```

outside of the condition. This will show the value that you're comparing it to.

Answer (score 2):

Please check following.

1. Check if there more than one variable in a package with **"Key"** name.
2. check if you verifying at correct place in package.

[image: Package Image]

Comment: Hi Vikas,
1. There is only 1 variable with the name "Key".
2. I also verified the location in package. It seems to be correct.

Comment: This is bit strange, did you verify it after your c# tbb execution, because package result may change after each tbb execution...otherwise   try using any other variable name...